# Why can't I pass an array(within an array) as an argument?

Tags: vba, excel, arguments

I have an array of arrays `arrAggregatedArrays(1 to 8)`

I can call a sub like this:

```
call sub(ArrNewClient)
```

But I get a compile error: "Type Mismatch" if I try this:

```
call sub(arrAggregatedArrays(1))
```

Why? And is there a way around it?

and why does it not recognise `arrAggregatedArrays(1)` as an array even though it will perform functions like `UBound` on it like normal?

```
Public arrAggregatedArrays()     As Variant      '/ Holds all the sheet-Data Arrays
```

'/ Declared in a seperate module

```
      ReDim arrAggregatedArrays(1 To 8)
            arrAggregatedArrays(1) = arrNewClient
            arrAggregatedArrays(2) = arrExistingClient
            arrAggregatedArrays(3) = arrGroupSchemes
            arrAggregatedArrays(4) = arrOther
            arrAggregatedArrays(5) = arrMcOngoing
            arrAggregatedArrays(6) = arrJhOngoing
            arrAggregatedArrays(7) = arrAegonQuilterArc
            arrAggregatedArrays(8) = arrAscentric

      Call FilterSheetArrayForColumns(arrAggregatedArrays(1))

Public Sub FilterSheetArrayForColumns(ByRef arrCurrentArray() As Variant)
```

and a screenshot:

[image: Compile Error]

Comment: You need to show us your declarations and how this variable is initialized.

Comment: Apologies, details added.

Comment: @Zak - Now we just need to see your function declaration for `FilterSheetArrayForColumns()`. My guess is you're receiving it as `a() As Variant` instead of `a As Variant`. Variants are special. The variable can be used by itself to represent an array.

Comment: so what's the difference between passing an array as `array` and as `array()` ?

Comment: @Zak - I've added an answer to try to explain the difference.

Comment: Are you trying to pass one of the nested arrays into a sub to be used as the `Criteria1:=arrCurrentArray` parameter in an [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx)? If so, you need to wrap the array var in brackets; e.g. `Criteria1:=(arrCurrentArray)`. I cannot explain adequately why but it has to be in brackets to be recognized as an array.

Comment: No. It's just that up until this point, I've always dimmed arrays as `dim array() as variant` and defined arguments as `byref array() as variant`. This is the first time I've tried putting arrays inside another array. Now that I know there's a difference between how a macro treats `array` and `array()` I want to understand why/ what the program thinks the difference is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `Variant` array in one of two ways:

```
Dim v1() As Variant
Dim v2: v2 = Array()
```

With the former, you receive the array as a subroutine parameter using the `v1()` notation, like with any other data type array in VBA. With the latter, you'll need to receive it as a normal variable, without the array notation.

Variants are special because they can hold many types, including array types, which is why the `v = Array()` syntax works. When done this way, they should be treated like any other variable and passed that way in and out of subroutines.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why/how `array` and `array()` are different from one another, in terms of how the program perceives / operates on them?

Comment: I'd like to understand the underlying concepts involved.

Comment: and if I can't pass `array` to a function expecting `array()` does that also mean I can't pass `array()` to a function expecting `array` ?

Comment: There isn't much of a difference between the two, other than how they're passed. A `Variant` variable can be used to store any type of array. For example, you could `Dim s(0) As String` and then assign it to a `Variant` like so: `Dim v As Variant: v = s`. So it may help conceptually to think of it as something generic that can hold more than just an intrinsic value. I'm sure you've seen examples of objects being assigned to variants as well.

Comment: There is a minor difference between: `Dim v1() As Variant` and `Dim v2 As Variant: v2 = Array()`. The latter can have its bounds safely tested (`LBound = 0`, `UBound = -1`) which can be beneficial if you need to dynamically resize it based on its current size: `ReDim v2(UBound(v2) + 1)`, for example. This is not possible using the former method.

Comment: Ok. but why are they different? Sorry if I'm not getting it, but I want to understand what the source of these differences are. Is it a case of one is a variant array, whereas the other is an array held within a variant object?

Comment: They're both essentially the same. If you tested them with `VarType()`, for example, they'd both report an "array of variants" (value `8204`, which is vbArray `8192` + vbVariant `12`). Assigning an array to a variant is no different than assigning an intrinsic value (bool, string, int) or an object to a variant in the sense that variants can used to represent other data types, including arrays. It's probably just more confusing in this example because there are two ways to accomplish essentially the same thing.

Comment: Okay. but then why do I have to know beforehand how it was declared before I pass it as an argument?

Comment: My assumption is that it's because `Dim v() As Variant` is created as a `SAFEARRAY` internally (like all typed arrays in VBA) demanding `()` notation whereas `v = Array()` is created as a `Variant` that points to a `SAFEARRAY` internally.

Comment: Sorry, what's a `SAFEARRAY`?

Comment: SAFEARRAYs are the internal implementation of a VBA array. Along with BSTRs and VARIANTs, they make up part of the essential OLE/COM foundation of which languages like VB6, VBA, and VBScript are built upon. [This page](http://www.roblocher.com/whitepapers/oletypes.html) may be of interest to you.

Comment: It's strange that you keep implying that these two are the same... and then  in the next breath you show how they are not. They are not the same at all. An array is an SAFEARRAY. A variant is VBA's implementation of a tagged union. The variant is much like a container able to hold all other variable types (with the exception of the fixed-length string). A variant can be assigned one type in one instance and then be assigned another in the next instance. An array on the other hand, must always be an array while in scope. Yet, the variant is capable of being assigned arrays as well.

Comment: VarType() and also TypeName() only report the variant's subtype. Even if you try them on a variant that has not been assigned a value, this is still true and the subtype Empty will be reported. So the fact that you get 8204 for both of these variables is misleading. They are not the same at all.

Comment: @ExcelHero - I originally thought he was asking how the two are _functionally_ different because he was asking about passing to functions. From a functional standpoint, as arrays, they're nearly identical. But I said all the same things you did (SAFEARRAY vs Variant, Variants are generic containers, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you need to show more on the implementation you are using. This works for me.

```
Sub arr_test()
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(2, 3, 4), _
                Array(3, 4, 5), Array(4, 5, 6))

    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 1) & ":" & UBound(arr, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(arr(1), 1) & ":" & UBound(arr(1), 1)

    Call arr_sub(arr)
    Call arr_sub(arr(1))

End Sub

Sub arr_sub(tarr As Variant)
    Debug.Print "arr_sub - "; LBound(tarr, 1) & ":" & UBound(tarr, 1)
End Sub
```

Results from the Immediate window:

```
arr_test
0:3
0:2
arr_sub - 0:3
arr_sub - 0:2
```

Comment: Apologies, details added.